# Add a List<object> to EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list

I'm playing around with EF, trying to get my bearings. Right now I'm writing a blackjack game for a website. The problem is that my whenever I pull a `GameState` from the database, the `playerHand`, `dealerHand`, `theDeck`, and `dealerHidden` properties are null.

```
public class GameState
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int gameSession { get; set; }
    public int playerScore { get; set; }
    public int dealerScore { get; set; }
    public Deck theDeck { get; set; }
    public List<Cards> playerHand { get; set; }
    public List<Cards> dealerHand { get; set; }
    public Cards dealerHidden { get; set; }
    public bool gameOver { get; set; }
}

public class Cards
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int cardId { get; set; }
    public string cardName { get; set; }
    public int cardValue { get; set; }
}

public class GameStateContext : DbContext
{
    public GameStateContext() : base("MyContext")
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<GameState>().HasRequired(e => e.theDeck);
        modelBuilder.Entity<GameState>().HasRequired(e => e.dealerHand).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<GameState>().HasRequired(e => e.playerHand).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<GameState>().HasOptional(e => e.dealerHidden);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Deck>().HasRequired(e => e.cards).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<GameState> GameStates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Deck> Decks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Card> Cards { get; set; }
}
```

The cards and deck table are populated. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: post code for Cards please.

Comment: Did you do something like context.Cards.Add(myCard)?

Comment: Yea. That happens when a deck is built for the first time, which I just realized is a mistake.

Comment: What is the real problem? Your initial description explains problem with fetching related data from the database (= you need eager loading). You follow with some model builder related issue and discussion under deleted answer contained something about persistence issue and mentioned working solution with serialization and deserialization.

Comment: My GameState object is fine before going into EF, when it comes out playerHand, dealerHand, and dealerHidden are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you either need to make your navigation properties i.e.  playerHand, dealerHand, theDeck, and dealerHidden lazy loadable by making them virtual properties, or you need to eagerly load them when you query GameState.

```
myDBContext.GameStates.Include("playerHand").Include("dealerHand").Include("theDeck").Include("dealerHidden").where(...);
```

here is a decent explanation about how entity framework treats related objects:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: I actually just came over to post this! Here's the code I ended up using:

`var gameState =     (context.GameStates.Include(c => c.theDeck.cards).Include(c=>c.playerHand).Include(c => c.dealerHand).Include(c=>c.dealerHidden).Where(c => c.gameSession == sessionId)
                                        .Where(c => c.gameOver == false)).FirstOrDefault();`